# VisualSVN Merge Conflict assistance

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am trying to merge a feature branch back to the trunk and I am getting

> One or more files are in a conflicted state.
>
> Conflicted
>
> - C:\Projects\MyaPP\frmMain.vb
>     C:\Projects\MyaPP\frmMain.Designer.vb Conflicted
>     C:\Projects\MyaPP\Controls\frmView.Designer.vb

Here is a brief history on what happened.

From the trunk, a feature branch (Feature1) was created, in May 2011.
From the trunk, a feature branch (Feature2) was created, in July 2011.

then last Friday, branches/Feature2 was merged back into the trunk successfully. Then today I attempted to merge branches/Feature1 I am getting the error above.

any advice on how I should handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used VisualSVN but conflict resolution should be similar in all SVN clients. You should compare (or 'diff') the conflicted files (in TortoiseSVN its right click-> resolved... and then right click..compare on the items in the list). Scroll through the files and copy over to the working copy the lines from Feature1 you want to merge into the trunk. When you are satisfied, save & close and then mark the conflict as 'resolved'.

Hope you can extrapolate from this.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal when you have many feature branches. You have to ensure that the branch that you want to reintegrate back is synchronized with the Trunk revisions.

Subversion tracks the last revision number when you created that Feature Branch 1. Since the trunk revisions have moved on, it then tries to do a diff and merge against the Feature Branch 1. That is why you have conflicts.

You need to do an "svn merge" from the Trunk to that feature branch using the Revision number from the time you started the FB1 up to the HEAD revision and then resolve all the conflicts.

To do the merge from the trunk to the branch, here are the steps:

1. Do an "svn checkout" from the feature branch.
2. Do an "svn merge" from the trunk to the working copy of the feature branch.
3. Resolve conflicts.
4. Do an "svn commit" of the working copy of the feature branch.

Once this is done you can now proceed with the reintegration back to the trunk.